# Using Javascript to add to another website's cart

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, magento, e-commerce

Bit of an odd question admittedly, hopefully someone will be able to help.

**Background:**
I am writing a small eCommerce website using Laravel, but due to restrictions of one of the product suppliers, I need to redirect the checkout of their products to their website which runs Magento.

**Proposed Idea:**
I want to be able to add the product to the cart on my website and then when they check out it redirects to their website and auto-fills their cart.

The only way I can think of to do this is to use Javascript to click the "add to cart" button on the supplier's corresponding page for each item. Obviously not ideal as it would have to launch each page which would seem troublesome with many items. Are there any other ways to accomplish this simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will certainly not work as this sounds like a XSS Attack on your user. Your website can not execute any actions on another website in the background - at least as long there are no CORS headers to allow for that.

You need to find a way to submit the orders to your supplier via some kind of api. Please do not try to go your proposed way, this is a really bad idea.

Comment: Also it could be not only technical limitations, but legal ones, too, depending on the country the asker lives in

Comment: Damn, didn't even consider that. Thanks, Alex and Yunzen.